# Not able to find roots of linear 2nd order homogeneous dif. equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, roots, quadratics

I am trying to find the roots of the differential equation $y''+7y'+6y=0$.

I assume the following:

$$
y=e^{rx}  \\
y'=r*e^{rx} \\
y''=r^2*e^{rx}.
$$
Then I substitute that into the dif. equation:
$$
r^2*e^{rx}+7*(r*e^{rx})+2*e^{rx}=0 \\
e^{rx}*(r^2+7r+2)=0.
$$
And I end up with the following quadratic equation which I need to find the roots of:
$$
r^2+7r+2=0.
$$

It's impossible to factor, so I tried to use the quadratic formula but end up with wrong results for r:
$$
r=((-7+\sqrt{7^2-4*1*2})/(2*1))=-0.298 \\
r=((-7-\sqrt{7^2-4*1*2})/(2*1))=-6.702.
$$
I used the same method for all other linear 2nd order homogeneous differential equations where I got correct results. But this time, I messed up.

What did I do wrong?!

Comment: In the original ODE you write $6y$, but later on this term becomes $2y$, for no reasons. The $2$ should be a $6$.

Comment: @Ernie060 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original equation is: $$y''+7y'+6y=0$$

After you substitute $e^{rx}$ you write:

$$r^2e^{rx}+7re^{rx}+\color{red}{2}e^{rx}=0$$

The $\color{red}{2}$ should be a $\color{green}{6}.$